# Run Two Different Jars with different java versions on same linux server

Tags: java, linux, jar, version

I have linux server with java 1.6 installed on it and many runnable jars running using the 1.6 version of java. I want to deploy my runnable jar on the same linux server with 1.8 java version configuration.

I tried upgrading the java version on the server to 1.8 but some of the earlier applications running on 1.6 started showing error.

So is it possible for me to run my jar on the same server with 1.8 java version or specify the path in my project to pick the java version from that path?

Comment: You can have multiple java versions installed on the same linux machine.

Comment: It's pretty much easy to just do it this way
<path_to_jre>/bin/java -jar Executable.jar